# How to use Matlab to extract certain data from text-file

Tags: matlab, position, text-files

Here is the data and the formatting of the data that I need to extract into Matlab.

Here are a few sample lines :

```
At time 1371600873.947
- Translation: [-0.805, -0.394, -0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.470, 0.882]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.980]

At time 1371600874.946
- Translation: [-0.805, -0.394, -0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.470, 0.882]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.980]

At time 1371600875.979
- Translation: [-0.805, -0.394, -0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.470, 0.883]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.977]
```

What I need: I need a program to read on the first two values in the translation data set. This is for [x,y,z] positioning, and I only want to extract the x and y values and then setup two arrays, one for all the x-values and the other for the y-values, which will then be plotted. This is the typical format shown above and I really need an effective way of sorting out just the two x and y values from above.

I have looked into data extraction from text files, but I am afraid that my inexperience with Matlab may prove this task a little ahead of myself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You REALLY want to look into `regexp` - regular expressions are a very powerful tool for handling text, you are doing yourself a great favour learning to use them. see doc [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html).

Comment: Here's an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10179539/411882) that will help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use regexp in Matlab to return the value of a variable from a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176116/use-regexp-in-matlab-to-return-the-value-of-a-variable-from-a-text-file)